# What is the difference between x[1, 1] and x.item(1, 1)?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

In NumPy arrays, I have been always using brackets to specify an element of an array.

For example,

```
x = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
```

Then, `x[1, 1]` may be used to represent the item at the 1-st row and the 1-st column.

But today, I saw that some people are using `x.item(1, 1)` instead.

Are `x.item(1, 1)` and `x[1, 1]` exactly the same, or are there any differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.item()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) copies an element of an array to a standard Python scalar and return it. But when you are using x[1, 1] - you reference a specific element from the nd-array.